# Android In-app subscription purchase with multiple user on a single device

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment-processing, in-app-subscription

I am developing an app with android in-app subscription purchase with a self login procedure, basically which means multiple user can use single device to access app. Everything works fine as long as i use a single user in my app, but as i logout and login another user and try to do a subscription purchase it either tells me you already have this subscription or changes my subscription to new requested subscription.
This happens because previous user had a subscription which is reflecting in this user, as subscriptions/purchases are associated with the primary play store account.
So How can i manage this situation with multiple user each with a same or different subscription on a single device? Is it possible ? 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It’s a mess and you hardly find any information from Google about it. Since purchases are bound to the Google account, we ended up not showing buying options when detecting (active) subscriptions for the current user.

Comment: Have you found a way to solve this problem? I am facing the same proble with my app.

Comment: @appLogic i didn't found any proper to do so,
i added a payload in each transaction which was userIdand when a new user tried to buy a subscription already bought on same device with another  user , i show him a message that this plan is already bought from following user(get this user from userId) either change your playstore account or switch to previous user